# Override Magento Catalog Detail view and List view

Tags: product, overrides, catalog, magento-2.1

i am using Magento CE 2.1 version, i am trying to override Product detail view (Catalog).

#### My folder structure is

[image: my folder structure]

What are the files to override for Detail view and List view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want override a template in: vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml

You create a file have path as: app/design/frontend///Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

Comment: Hi,
I tried to fall back the list.phtml, vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml in the path ,
app\design\frontend\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\list.phtml .

But it's not working.

Could you please say me where I did mistake